# Constrained matrix least squares with a set of quadratic form constraints

Tags: optimization, least-squares

WHAT I DON'T KNOW:

MATRIX CASE: I have a matrix equation $Y=AB$, where  Y and A are given and we would like to find $B$. Here are more information: $Y \in R^{m \times n}$ with $m >n$,  $A \in R^{m \times k}$ and $B \in R^{k \times n}$ with $k <n$.  Obviously the problem is over-determined. Let $\{ \textbf{b}_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ denote the column vectors of $B$. Now here are the constraints on these vectors.
$\textbf{b}_i^TR_i \textbf{b}_i,i=0,1,2,\cdots,n$. How to formulate this problem as an optimization equation and solve it minimizing the least squares or Frobenius norm?

WHAT I KNOW

VECTOR CASE:
I know for $\textbf{y}=A\textbf{b}~~$ ($\mathbf{y,b}$ are vectors) and  with the constrain $\textbf{b}^TR \textbf{b}$, the optimization formulation is

\begin{equation}
\underset{\textbf{b}}{\operatorname{min}}~ \| \textbf{y} - A \textbf{b} \|^{2} + \lambda (\textbf{b}^T R \textbf{b})
\end{equation}

with the least squares solution

\begin{equation}
\widehat{\textbf{b}}=\left(A^T A +\lambda R \right)^{-1}A^T \textbf{y}~
\end{equation}

Could anyone help me with the matrix case?

Comment: If you already know how to solve for one column, then you can repeat the same procedure for each column. I'm more interested on how you plan to solve the constraint though. Is it through fixed penalty $\lambda$? Quadratic equality constraint seems hard.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have in a form you are familiar with, you can exploit the fact that $\text{vec}(Y) = (I^{k\times k} \otimes A) \text{vec}(B)$ where $I^{k\times k}$ denotes the identity matrix and $\otimes$ is the kronecker product.